# Static Deploy gives error

Tags: magento-2.1, database, static-block, static-content-deploy, bin-magento

When I do the this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it gives me error of

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>   NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default"
>   and "developer" modes.

In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option:

> 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f'

and my website will be in death white screen can you please help me how I'm gonna fix this thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try below command it will deploy your content

```
php bin/magento set up:static-content:deploy -f
```

as per Magento 2's documentation

> Default and developer modes: Magento generates them on demand, but the
>   rest are cached in a file for speed of access.

From Magento 2.2 Manual static content deploy is not required. But you may still do that with -f option.

[Source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Because I installed aramex modules for my shipping method they Gave me steps to deploy it so even I will not run the php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy the aramex module will be running properly? thank you.

Comment: Please disable the extension then try it again

Comment: @kd_mj0312 If your magento 2 store is in the development mode then you don't need to deploy content. Your module should work fine. If there is no error in module.